# How to use UIPopoverController with fromRect

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller

Could anyone please tell me what the `rect` and `view` should be? I do not understand what I shall pass to the selector. An example would be great!

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this pretty often.  Let's say you want to tap on an image and present a popover with information about it.  Assuming you have a gesture recognizer with the selector method `(handleImageTap:)` on your image, here would be an example code to make that happen:

```
- (void)handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    // initialize your popover view controller and assign it to your popoverController
    MyPopoverViewController *content = [[MyPopoverViewController alloc] init];
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:content];
    popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(600, 600);
    popoverController.delegate = self;
    [content release];

    if (popoverController.popoverVisible == NO) {
        // you can find the tappedImage through the gesture by searching up superviews if you don't already have a reference to it;
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[tappedImage frame] inView:self.view 
        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];                  
    }
    else {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

So basically, `view` will be self.view becuase you are displaying it from the current view controller.  The `rect` is just whatever rect you want the popover to display from.  In this case, it is set up to be displayed from the frame of an image.  I hope this helps you.  If something is still confusing, I'll be happy to try and clear it up

Comment: Thank you, no need for further explanation, this is more than enough! I understand what they are now.